# RenderToJpegAsync() giving System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException

Tags: windows-phone-8, image-processing, nokia, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

I am trying to use Nokia Imaging SDK to filter a live camera stream and saving the stream data to an Image file. I am using Camera Stream example from Nokia Imaging.

Filter is working properly, but when I try to use EditingSession to save image, it gives me System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException . The code I am using to save image is -

```
MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary(); 
IBuffer jpegOut = await effects.Session.RenderToJpegAsync();
library.SavePicture(FileNamePrefix + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".jpg", jpegOut.AsStream());
```

While effects.Session is actually the EditingSession used to apply filter on camera stream. I've used the same method to capture static image data, now I can't use it for streaming data. Any other way to save the filtered image??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by capturing `MediaElement` into a `WritableBitmap`. Saving the image requires `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB` capability as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10266379/1079901)