# How to erase part of Image by finger on WinPhone?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have heavy task for me.
I have simple WinPhone silverlight page, on page I have Canvas.
On Canvas I have Image control with photo.
I want that user can erase part of picture on Image control by finger (similary on erase in MS  Paint).
And after change photo user can save new image.

I don't fins solution for this task.

Could you please help me?

Comment: a small addition: I added aditional photo on canvas, and I want that this photo use as bacground. canvas->photo(as backgound)->photo thatI want erase

Answer (score 0):

Put another Canvas into the Canvas, overlaying the Image. Let the user draw on this new Canvas ([Drawing things on a Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008895/drawing-things-on-a-canvas)). Save the result by calling WritableBitmap.Render(parentCanvas) and SaveJpeg ([Saving a WriteableBitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634970/saving-a-writeablebitmap)).
You might need to add some Transformations to handle different Image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your image inside a Grid and put an [InkPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202902%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) on top and to erase just use white ink. Here is a getStarted to use the inkpresenter : [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662946%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Finally when you want to save the result, just saved the grid using WriteableBitmap.Render and MediaLibrary.SaveJpeg to save it to the user Library.